# Where are the permissions need for a content creator to set the URL and path alias for an article?

Tags: path-aliases, users

I am creating content as a user given the necessary permissions but I can't find the settings needed to set the URL and path alias for an article I am creating.

I have checked all the permissions and there doesn't seem to be anything preventing?

Does pathauto and the URL fields only work for admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the Permissions settings - `/admin/people/permissions` under Path. Using the [Filter Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/filter_perms) module, entering `path` in the `Filter list` control brings up the checkboxes quickly.

The settings to change are `Create and edit URL aliases` and `Administer URL aliases` if that is also necessary

Answer (score 0):

It is *Administer content* under *Node*.

Comment: Can you give an example link to `Node`?

Comment: Under `/admin/people/permissions`, under section *Node*, permission *Administer content* is responsible for allowing a user to change the node path alias.

Comment: Does doing this enable the _URL alias_ field in the content creation form? I have checked and it doesn't. It is the _Path_ settings under _Permissions_ which allows it.

Comment: The relevant source is [`path_form_node_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21path%21path.module/function/path_form_node_form_alter/7).  You can see that the `#access` on `$form['path']` is controlled by two permissions, `'create url aliases'` and `'administer url aliases'`.